# How to change a two-level jQuery expanding menu to be three levels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a 2-level expanding menu that triggers using jQuery. I've been going round in circles and keep confusing myself on how to update the if/else statements to work for multi-level (a third-tier). I wondered if anyone could help me finish this off?

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/07bLdq2p/)

Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="MobileNav" class="mobile-nav">
  <li class="mobile-nav__item">
    <button type="button" class="js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link" data-level="1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 1 - 1</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-level="2">
      <li class="mobile-nav__item">
        <button type="button" class="js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 2 - 1</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-level="3">
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
              <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 3 - 1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>     
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobile-nav__item">
    <button type="button" class="js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link" data-level="1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 1 - 2</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-level="2">
      <li class="mobile-nav__item">
        <button type="button" class="js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 2 - 1</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-level="3">
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
              <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 3 - 1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
              <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 3 - 2</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
              <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 3 - 3</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>     
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-nav__item">
        <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
          <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 2 - 2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-nav__item">
        <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
          <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 2 - 3</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var accordion_head  = $('.js-toggle-submenu'),
accordion_body  = $('.mobile-nav__dropdown');

accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
    accordion_head.removeClass('active');
  } else {
    accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
    $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
    accordion_head.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your dropdown working to any nested level. You are expanding your menu using condition to check `active` class which is not required. Toggle `active` class and `slideUp` or `slideDown` with only one line `code`.

**Here is the Demo**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var accordion_head  = $('.js-toggle-submenu');

  accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
      $(this).next('.mobile-nav__dropdown').find('.active').removeClass('active').next('.mobile-nav__dropdown').slideUp('normal');
    }
    $(this).parent('li').siblings('li').find('.active').removeClass('active').next('.mobile-nav__dropdown').slideUp('normal');
    $(this).stop().toggleClass('active').next('.mobile-nav__dropdown').stop().slideToggle('normal');
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile-nav__dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="MobileNav" class="mobile-nav">
  <li class="mobile-nav__item">
    <button type="button" class="js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link" data-level="1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 1 - 1</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-level="2">
      <li class="mobile-nav__item">
        <button type="button" class="js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 2 - 1</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-level="3">
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
              <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 3 - 1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>     
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobile-nav__item">
    <button type="button" class="js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link" data-level="1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 1 - 2</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-level="2">
      <li class="mobile-nav__item">
        <button type="button" class="js-toggle-submenu mobile-nav__link" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 2 - 1</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="mobile-nav__dropdown" data-level="3">
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
              <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 3 - 1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
              <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 3 - 2</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="mobile-nav__item">
            <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
              <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 3 - 3</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>     
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-nav__item">
        <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
          <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 2 - 2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-nav__item">
        <a href="/" class="mobile-nav__sublist-link">
          <span class="mobile-nav__label">Link Level 2 - 3</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your solution. The issue with this is when you open another dropdown the open ones don't close. Is that possible or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: @user2498890 I have edited snippet. Please check. I hope it works as you expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different approach - expand immediate children using -
`accordion_body  = accordion_head.children('.mobile-nav__dropdown');`

The updated jsfiddle is - https://jsfiddle.net/ybemnfpk/